# Deleted method in Observer not get called on pivot array sync

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, relationship, observers

I have two tables Content and Languages and a Pivot table Content Languages. When I edit the content by attaching language Ids I used sync() (It has Id and a pivot column in $syncData). Also, have an ContentLanguageObserver to trigger some events at created and deleted events. But, only the `created` event is getting called on sync()  and `deleted` method is never get called on deleting the value from content, but the DB is got updated.

I have several other related fields too, they're working fine on both events as they don't have a pivot array to updated at sync().

A working relationship in my code base:

App/Content.php

```
 public function genres(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class, 'content_genres')->using('App\ContentGenre')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Sync function `ContentService.php`, where $genres is an array of ids only, this triggers `created` and `deleted` in the `ContentGenreObserver.php`

```
  $content->genres()->sync($genres);
```

Issue with Lanuguages:

```
public function audioLanguage() {
    
    return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class, 'content_languages')->select('languages.id','languages.english_name')->wherePivot('language_type', '=', Language::AudioLanguage)->using(ContentLanguage::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

Sync function `ContentService.php`, where $syncData is an array of ids and pivot column, this triggers only `created` but not `deleted` in the `ContentLanguageObserver.php`

```
 $content->audioLanguage()->sync($syncData);
```